# Move to element using selenium webdriver / python / chromedriver?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run an automated test in Chromedriver, if I need to click on an element below the horizon of my screen, I get the following error -

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1068, 1064)\n  (Session info: chrome=33.0.1750.152)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.6.232908,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.0 x86_64)'
```

I tried this -

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("element")
move = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button)
move.perform()
```

But apparently that's only for when I want to hover the mouse over an element.  Is there something I'm missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Check for `displayed property`,if it is false, you can execute javascript `element.scrollIntoView(true);` to bring the element into the viewport.